# Rails mail function sending emails twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

Two emails are being sent by the code below, both with an identical message-ID, yet I suspect its probably my code.

controller:

```
 @payment.update_attributes(:status => "Confirmed")
```

Payments Modal:

```
before_save :check_if_confirmed
before_update :check_if_confirmed

def check_if_confirmed
  if status == "Confirmed"
    tickets.each do |t|
     t.status = "Confirmed"
     t.save
  end
    Emailer.payment(self,user.id,user.full_name, user.email, self.total, self.id).deliver
end
```

Emailer.rb

```
def payment(payment, user_id, buyer_name, email = payment.user.email, price, payment_id)
....
   mail(:from => "John Smith <john@smith.com>", :to => email, :subject => "Whatever")
```

The email is being sent once then immediately being sent again. Its a receipt so naturally I need to stop it being sent twice.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`before_save :check_if_confirmed` is fired every time the record is being saved (even if its created)

`before_update :check_if_confirmed` is fired when record was already created and the data is just updated.

You are using the wrong callbacks, that are firing mail delivering twice. `before_save` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of the callbacks
before_save :check_if_confirmed
before_update :check_if_confirmed

Use only one of them